# Sketch iOS Design

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, user-experience

In Sketch, the OSX program for UX design, I was curious about:

Once I create a design, how do I make that design work in Storyboard in XCode or programmatically?

Since by making a design, all I am making is an image, how do I make it come alive and have the user actually interact with it in XCode?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no direct import to the best of my knowledge. You will need to re-create the interface in Interface Builder (part of Xcode) and then write the code in Xcode to make it "come alive". This is usually an iterative process. The user will not interact with Xcode at all - once you've written the app you compile it and distribute it via Ad-Hoc distribution or the App Store

Comment: Lol. I know this. Say I have my design. I export all my elements in 1x and 2x. How do I support the different screen sizes for iPhones and iPads?

Comment: You need to load your images into an asset catalogue. Then either selecting the image inside Interface Builder or using API like `imageNamed:` will select the correct image depending on scale and trait collection.

Comment: I know this answer is quite old, but I've finally come to a new solution other than writing the code yourself. I created a Sketch Plugin (http://sketchcodeflow.com) that does just this! It transforms artboards into Objective-C UIKit and SpriteKit code. Even exports into asset catalogs for @1-3x. Simply #import and write one line of code in your ViewController and you got your app running. Of course, that's UI only. You'll have to write all logic yourself though there are a few features to help improve your experience such as animations and parallax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You recreate the objects in the interface builder.

You change the background colour of the view to the background colour of your design.
Save your button images and set them to the background images of buttons.
etc.

Answer (score 2):

> how do I make it come alive and have the user actually interact with it

That question is basically the same as this question:

> After I draw my design on the whiteboard, how do I turn that into an app?

There's no tool that takes a Sketch file or a whiteboard and turns it into an app.
The answer in both cases is the same: you use the tools provided by Apple (Xcode, Objective-C or Swift, the iOS SDK, xibs or storyboards) to write a program that implements your design.  If you don't know how to use those tools, you need to work through some tutorials to learn them before you start working on implementing your own design.  If you don't know how to program at all, I suggest starting with some programming tutorials that **don't** involve iOS programming, because learning the basics of programming is already complicated, even without adding the peculiarities of iOS development.

Comment: I know how to code OC fluently. Once I create a wonderful design on Sketch, I just don't know how to put that into XCode and have the user interact with it?

Comment: Perhaps [this website/book](https://designcode.io/xcode) is what you're looking for.